# Django and autocomplete quick and dirty approach

Tags: javascript, python, django, autocomplete

Can anyone suggest a simple quick and dirty method of providing autocomplete for a text field for example. I may also consider a drop down later on. I can think of a few strategies for doing this, but I'd like to stay away from non-standard Django packages.

Are there any JS libraries that would help? I am thinking for speed, I simply need to query the options - i.e. the text fields and let the JS/JQuery figure out which one works best and I'll expose the JS/JQuery library to that list of say keywords.

Any suggestions to save time?

Comment: I don't know of any js framework/library that can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is pretty much one option I'd suggest](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light):

> django-autocomplete-light’s purpose is to enable autocompletes quickly and properly in a django project: it is the fruit of half a decade of R&D and thousands of contributions. It was designed for Django so that every part overridable or reusable independently. It is stable, tested, documented and fully supported: it tries to be a good neighbour in Django ecosystem.

Its easy to setup, has no dependencies and plays very well with django.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI contains quite easy way to create autocomplete inputs.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

You can check working sample from here:

https://michalcodes4life.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/ajax-autocomplete-search-with-jquery-django-and-tastypie/